# Head motion is not working with Hololens 2 after upgrading Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I am building an app in Unity for Hololens 2. I have an cube in my scene. With App built using earlier version of Unity, the cube remains stationary relative to the surrounding.

Now I have moved my project from Unity version 2018.4.34.f1 to 2020.3.20.f1(on another desktop).

The scene in front of me remains intact as a function of head motion. If I move my head up, cube also moves up and so on. I would like the object to remain stationary in the scene.

I have installed the OpenXR plugin as well.

What could I be doing wrong ?

Comment: Is there any script to hook your cube and camera? If you need more help, please provide more information about the behavior of objects in the scene after upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to Unity 2020.3 LTS, please use the Mixed Reality Feature Tool to import the Mixed Reality OpenXR Plugin and Unity OpenXR plugin and follow this step-by-step guide to setting up your XR configuration: [6. Configure XR Plugin Management for OpenXR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/porting-apps/migrate-a-unity-2019-project-to-openxr#6-configure-xr-plugin-management-for-openxr). Also, we suggest importing the latest stable version of MRTK and leveraging MRTK Project Configurator to abstract most configures for you.